# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied. Removing directory using OS module

Tags: python

I recently switched to Blender 4.0 and registered for all my Blender files in the *Preferences > System > Register*. I can't remove any directory or file from the Blender interpreter. Let me know if I'm forgetting anything.

My code:

```
import os
path = r'MY_FOLDER'
os.remove(path)
```

[image]

Comment: Is the file in use? Will success remove it from the operating system UI? Have you had any success using other IDEs? Posting to stackoverflow should make it easier to get answers since the question does not contain any blender API.

Comment: Hello. This is obviously not a blender related question. But make sure you have sufficient write access in the drive. Make sure you launch Blender in admin mode.